# zoom in and zoom out for Image in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to zoom in and zoom out an Image in WP7,C# without using pinch zooming. For example If I double tap on the browser it automatically zooms in and zooms out again if I double tap.

So when I do double tap it automatically zooms in the image and again if I do double tap it zooms out to normal size. could you please let me know how to achieve it.

Thanks,
Mugu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying a ScaleTransform to the image in the DoubleTap event handler.